# How to retrieve the list of files checked into mercurial for a given branchname and comment using python script?

Tags: python, mercurial

I have to write a python script to retrieve all the files from a branch for a given comment(used while checking in the code to mercurial) how can it be done?
i could not get much help from the examples i searched so can anyone please help me?
Also if someone could post the link to know about mercurial commands it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `hg help` is quite comprehensive. There is also the hg book: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/

In your case you want the output of `hg manifest` which list all files which belong to a certain revision. A small commit hook to check the new changesets for unwanted files can be found there: https://hg.openttdcoop.org/misc/files/tip/mercurial/hooks/check_commit.py
Mind, as long as you use the internal API as in that example, your script is considered derived work from mercurial and needs to use its GPL license, too. Use the 'normal' CLI to avoid that requirement.

Comment: Thank u . I am new to this python scripting and also have been using mercurial very minimal via tortoise UI. So please bare with me for some doubts. I went through the check_commit script. This script in "get_filedata" will check for particular file extension. Probably if i have to use something like this i need not do this right since i want to retrieve all the files for a given revision.

Comment: I did not say that script is a ready-made solution to your problem, it is for mine which blocks commits with unwanted files. You only ask for a method without describing your actual problem or goal in your question. If you really want to check every file in a (or every) commit (and not only changed or added) you'll need to use manifest to get a list of all files. But this script can help get you started along with the knowledge to use the manifest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i did mention in the description that my aim is to list all the files that were checked in for a given comment. i mean if i have checked in some 5 files for a comment "abc" then when i give this "abc" as input to my function it should list out all the names of the 5 files.

Comment: So you are interested only in the files *changed* (or added / removed) in a particular commit (mind comment != commit). If only the files touched by that commit then the ougput of `hg status` is of interest for you. And you can actually use a check similar to the one in the linked script which checks the filenames in that commit